# SQL Total count in JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc)

I used JOIN and I want to show total quantity in each order in a row.
I used this query but I think it's not the best way and it is too long.
is there a shorter and better way to do that?

**NOTE:** I want to show all columns with `Total_quantity_in_each_order` and I don't want to show `Quantity` column.
here is my code:

```
SELECT
OrderDetails.OrderDetailID,
OrderDetails.OrderID,
Orders.CustomerID,
Orders.EmployeeID,
Orders.OrderDate,
Orders.ShipperID,
SUM(Quantity) AS Total_quantity_in_each_order
FROM OrderDetails JOIN Orders
ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.OrderID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL, in general, and MySQL in particular allows you to aggregate by the primary key of a table and still reference other columns from that table.  So, assuming that `Orders.OrderId` is the primary key (a reasonable assumption), this is allowed:

```
SELECT o.*,
       SUM(od.Quantity) AS Total_quantity_in_each_order
FROM Orders o JOIN
     OrderDetails od
     ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
GROUP BY o.OrderID;
```

Note that no other columns from `OrderDetails` are included.

Apart from using a primary key or unique key in the `GROUP BY`, you need to list all the unaggregated columns in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's the best way

Answer (score 2):

When you use aggregate functions you should have every columns without aggregate functions in `group by` .

Your code does not work. Because you didn't have every columns without aggregate functions in `group by` . In addition, you have not specified the table name of the `Quantity` column. If there is a `Quantity` column in both tables, your code does not work.

This code should work. But I do not know if this is the result you wanted:

```
SELECT
OrderDetails.OrderDetailID,
Orders.OrderID,
Orders.CustomerID,
Orders.EmployeeID,
Orders.OrderDate,
Orders.ShipperID,
SUM(Quantity) AS Total_quantity_in_each_order
FROM OrderDetails JOIN Orders
ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY OrderDetails.OrderDetailID,
Orders.OrderID,
Orders.CustomerID,
Orders.EmployeeID,
Orders.OrderDate,
Orders.ShipperID;
```

**Update 1:**

If you need total quantity for each order this query might be what you need:

```
SELECT
Orders.OrderID,
Orders.CustomerID,
Orders.EmployeeID,
Orders.OrderDate,
Orders.ShipperID,
SUM(Quantity) AS Total_quantity_in_each_order
FROM OrderDetails JOIN Orders
ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY 
Orders.OrderID,
Orders.CustomerID,
Orders.EmployeeID,
Orders.OrderDate,
Orders.ShipperID;
```